# How many $4$ digit integers have the product of their digits equal to $5!$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many different $4$-digit integers have the product of their digits equal to $5!$? What is the largest of these integers?

I know $5!$ is $120$, but I'm really stuck.

Comment: Shouldn’t be fairly easy to write an exhaustive list of all such numbers?

Answer (score 2):

*Hints* :

$120 = 1\cdot 2^{3}\cdot 3\cdot 5$. So possible digits are : $1,2,3,4,5,6,8.$

You may assume that there is $8$ in your number and amount possible situations.

After assume there $6$ and so on.

Comment: If you have $8$ and $6$ you already have too many $2$s - once you have $8$ the highest possible next digit is $5$.

Comment: @MarkBennet no, I meant that suppose that there is $8$ in representation , then what digits there can be.

Comment: OK - I think what you have written is a little ambiguous, but I see what you mean now. You need the highest possible number in the most significant place to get the largest (to address the final part of the question).